# Lying about not already signing an offer

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, student

I made a rather stupid mistake: when I received an offer from my dream company and accepted it I was already in the interview process with another company.

About 1 week after accepting the offer, I was called by the other company and told that I am invited to the final interview.

I thought this is a good way to practice my interview skills and accepted it, even though I already took the offer. So, I went to the interview and (I think I) nailed it. At the end, I was asked if I have other offers. I was rather scared (but didn't show that) so I said I have an offer from the other company (and told the company's name), until next week. They asked me what it is about and I told them. They said that I will have the answer from them by then.

I didn't realize that I might be burning a bridge and now I don't know what to do. Will they talk to the other company about the offer?

To worsen this, I found out that the recruiter lead at the company from which I have the offer is a former boss of the HR person I met at the final interview.
Even more bad, these are world-level companies.

These are internship positions in software development (I'm still a student).
I don't even know why I said that..

What are the chances for this to backfire at me and what can I do about it?

LE: I was told by the technical interviwer that I will most likely receive an offer.

Comment: Do you have the written offer from the dream company with your start date on it?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have signed it.

Comment: Thank them for their time .Let them know that you were presented an offer by the other company and already signed it. Not much you can do now since you are now in contract and already starting a new job. Congrats!

Comment: @Isaiah3015 you missed my point: I do not want to cancel the acceptance of the first offer. I only came to the interview with the other company for interview experience and to get to know them better. It is just that I thought that it will do good and maybe this way I'd let the other company know what my skills are (who knows what future brings), but now I am afraid it will only do harm.

Comment: @LemonChris I think Isaiah means to go with the dream company you signed with and inform the second company immediately that you are no longer interested/available for the position on offer

Comment: @LemonChris Have you burned a bridge?  *Maybe* but *not likely*.  Your position with Dream Co. should help make your CV more attractive to other world-level companies, so even if Company B won't take you after this, there will be plenty of other fish, as they say.  If Company B is also a world-level company, they probably have so many applicants that they (a) won't remember you and (b) will have probably seen *way worse things.*.  I understand how you feel and you should absolutely learn from this experience, but don't waste time worrying about what might not even be a problem.

Comment: As to harm - you're overthinking it... as soon as you say you're no longer available they will forget you in a blink and move on to the next candidate - after all, this is only an internship

Comment: I wish you had seen [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/9707/1193) before you had the interview with the second company.

Comment: you didn't lie: you DO have another offer and you won't know for sire until next week (2nd company could offer you double, which _could_ change your mind)

Answer (score 4):

For future reference: Don't tell anyone where you are applying for jobs. That's the only thing you did wrong; you shouldn't tell one employer about a different employer.

When you apply for a job at company A, company A knows that you are applying elsewhere (the only exception is when you are happily employed, but see an outrageously great offer by A, and you are applying to them alone, but would be happy with your old job as well). So the fact that you are applying elsewhere is nothing any reasonable employer would hold against your.

And having other offers? Well, that will happen as well. And even after an offer, it is normal to have more interviews *until you signed a legally binding document*.

Answer (score 2):

Very doubtful they'd talk to the other company, BUT, and a big BUT is that the managers may know each other. They may talk or they may make a mention that so-so came to the interview and said he had a offer from his company. This is pure speculations though since I don't know them or who they are. I don't think you'd lose your job offer though.

I do not think you're in jeopardy of losing your dream job. In the future, stand your ground. If you are uncomfortable mentioning something, just say, "I don't want to disclose that." Just remember they are only spoken words, and in the end, they mean nothing. Don't be afraid of nothing.

Comment: Is not like I would ever do that again, but wouldn't not disclosing rise a red flag? Anyway, your answer is really helpful and calmed me a bit. Thank you.

Comment: No, I'm unsure why it would raise a red flag? People go to job interviews all the time, and when I got my first job, I went to multiple places for interviews, even with an offer that I signed. Just told them in the end I accepted another place.

Comment: Some companies *do* like to pretend that they are good enough that other companies shouldn't even be a consideration, so you *do* have companies that think having other interviews is a red flag. Luckily, these companies are probably not the ones you should accept any offers from in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see anything bad in going to this latter interview.
More,I even find it  polite from your side not ignoring them even after  having the signed offer from other employer in the pocket.

Interviews can be very interesting meetings where professionals exchange their opinion,their information  and improve their skills of presentation  no matter if the interviewee have been hired or not.
Is there anyone who can disagree that after each interview the job sicker is enriched by new experience and strengthener negotiation skill?

I would send them for sure one thank you letter focusing on  benefits of meeting them and talking to them,  expressing  the openness to cooperate with them someday in the future.

Since they already know that you have been hired by other company it will show to both companies(if managers know each other) that you don't calculate  anything,don`t hide anything and that you play on professional manners with open cards.

Answer (score 0):

You have been made an offer and it has been accepted they can't take that away because you have been for an interview with another business.

Don't panic over this, the reality is you went for the interview for experience, and applied to the role before you was given an offer.

However I hope that if this situation arises again, you know how you may differently handle it!

Comment: In America, if a Formal offer was given and they were to take it away because of a situation like this what would be the official reason?